# Refresh cron in AIX

Tags: cron, aix

I created a script that will add a cron job based on user specifications but it won't work since I need to refresh cron every time I append a job in crontab. Is there a way to refresh cron without killing the process?

Answer (score 3):

As long as your script uses `crontab` to add and delete job specifications for the user, there would be no need to restart the `cron` daemon.

The AIX 7.1 [cron manual page says](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds1/cron.htm):

> When you make changes to the crontab files using the `crontab` command, a message indicating the change is sent to the cron daemon.

See also [the `crontab` manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds1/crontab.htm).

The general flow of actions that your script would take:

1. Get user's crontab into a text file using `crontab -l >crontab.txt`.
2. Manipulate the text file by adding, removing or changing jobs specifications.
3. Load the user's crontab with the new specifications using `crontab crontab.txt`.

The commands in the first and last steps needs to be executed as the user (the first step could also be run as `crontab -l username >crontab.txt` as e.g. root).

This would work on any Unix using `cron`.

Comment: What if there are existing jobs? Do I have to put it in the same text file first then append the new job before loading it in the crontab?

Comment: @Shan As I mentioned, you would get the current crontab for the user, then modify that before loading it again. So yes, you would append new jobs to the file produced by `crontab -l`.

Answer (score -1):

AIX 7.1 [cron manual page says](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds1/cron.htm):

> The cron daemon reads the configuration file when it is activated and when it receives the hangup signal.

So just `kill -HUP cron_pid` should do it.

Comment: I already tried this but I would like to refresh my configuration without killing the process

Comment: @Shan The `kill` command sends signals to the process. In general, processes can be killed, i.e., they actually die, by receiving a signal. But in case of `cron` process it handles the signal, does not die, and re-reads its configuration.

Comment: The portion of the man page that you quoted is referring to cron's *configuration file*, `/etc/cronlog.conf`, not the crontab files themselves.

Comment: I cannot make this into an Answer for this question; when I manually edit a crontab file and HUP cron, the new cron job is not executed.

Comment: @JeffSchaller is correct, you either have to kill -9 cron_pid or use crontab on a crontab file as suggested by Kusalananda in the other answer to reload the crontab.